# Python POST запрос неверный ответ

Tags: python, post, requests

Использую python 3.8 и requests 2.7.0
Отправляя пост запрос логина на сайт https://forum.exbo.su/login я получаю в ответ не страницу, с ошибкой логина(должна быть ошибка, тк пароль и ник неверные), а страницу с текстом "You have been inactive for too long. Go back and try again." В чем проблема? Код ниже

```
import requests
login = 'login'
password = 'password'
api_sender = requests.session()
source = api_sender.post("https://forum.exbo.su/login", data={"identification": login,
                                                         "password": password,
                                                         "remember": False}).text
print(source)
```

В ответ получаю:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <title>EXBO Forum</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">

    <style>
      * {
       box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      body {
        font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 1.5;
        color: #333;
      }
      input,
      button,
      select,
      textarea {
        font-family: inherit;
        font-size: inherit;
        line-height: inherit;
      }
      a {
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #00ade4;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
      .container {
        margin: 100px auto;
        max-width: 450px;
        padding: 0 15px;
      }
      .button {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 15px 25px;
        background: #00ade4;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
        white-space: nowrap;
        font-weight: bold;
        border: 0;
      }
      .button:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      .button:active,
      .button.active {
        box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
      }
      .form {
        max-width: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      .form .button {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .form-control {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 2px solid #eee;
        border-radius: 4px;
        transition: border-color .15s;
      }
      .form-control:focus,
      .form-control.focus {
         border-color: #00ade4;
         outline: none;
      }
      .errors {
        color: #d83e3e;
      }
      .errors ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <p>
    You have been inactive for too long.
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="javascript:history.back()">
      Go back, to try again
    </a>
  </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это происходит из-за того, что сайт пытается защититься от [CSRF атаки (Double Submit Cookie)](https://habr.com/ru/post/318748/). Т.е. в вашем случае нужно дополнительно отправлять `headers={'x-csrf-token':..., 'cookie':...}`

Comment: Ваш ответ помог решить проблему, но как получать новый token, когда он обновляется. Т.е после входа в аккаунт через запрос, токен обновляется и попытки повторного входа дают ту же ошибку, что и была в начале. Как получить ответ от сайта, чтоб в нем содержался новый токен?

Comment: @Евгений сделать любой запрос, например, на главную страницу и достать из заголовков нужную инфу